# Why am I not able to get the download URL of my Firebase storage file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

To summarize the problem, users are uploading lots of PDF files to a storage bucket. After upload, the users have a button they can press that gets the download URL of the file they have selected and opens it in a new window.

```
const storageRef = Storage.ref(`Inbound_Forms/${selectedInbound.id}/${row.FileName}`);
  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    window.open(url, '__blank');
  });
```

The opening of the URL works about 95% of the time, but every once in a while when the user clicks the button to open the URL, this error gets thrown:

[image]

This would lead me to believe that the file does  not exist, but when I open up the bucket in the Firebase console, the file exists, and I can get download it via it's link in the console:

[image]

The path included: `/Inbound_Forms/5eE2Oytwrpc7FTkmH4gy` [image]

The solution for the time being is to have the users send me an email with a link to the page where the file is. I then track the original down in the bucket, download the file, and upload the exact same file with suffixed with 'copy', as seen in the image above. The new file works without issue, where the original continues throwing the same error. I just inform the user a copy has been uploaded, and they access it and continue on with their work.

There have been a few solutions I have looked into, but those worth mentioning are:
1) The file names have spaces. This does not seem to cause an issue, as even the copy I upload works without problems. And as stated before, this process works 95% of the time, many cases with spaces in the file name.
2) Storage rules. The same user has been able to open many other files with the same rules, including the newly uploaded copy.

Currently, I am unable to recreate this bug, as it happens so rarely. I thank anyone in advanced for and leads on what is going on here.

Comment: If you get that error, it means that the path you provided to the file didn't exist.  Without seeing the actual values from the code and comparing those to what you actually have, there's not much we can do here.  It might have to do with that space.  The building the path with a series of calls to child() instead of composing the full path with string concatenation.

Comment: @DougStevenson So I have taken the advice on using child() to create the ref, but it has not changed anything. 
```storageRef =Storage.ref()
.child('Inbound_Forms')
.child(selectedInbound.id)
.child(row.FileName);```
when I log out the references, both with child creation, and with template literal, they look to be the exact same. And to top that, I log out the values for both the copy file (referring to the image above) and the original and they have no differences. But the copy URL works, the original still throws the same 404 error with a ref created with child()

Comment: Isn't the ```Inbound_Forms/5eE2Oytwrpc7FTkmH4gy/Pacific Trans Tare Sheet``` thrown in the error the value that is generated in the code snippet above where I show how I am creating the storage ref? What more information can I give you that would help narrowing down the issue?

Comment: We need to be able to see the values of each one of those variables, and that they exactly match the path of the file in the bucket.  There is not enough information in the question now to verify everything exactly.  I suggest making everything clear by using log statements and pictures that don't truncate any values.